# when using separate click event for parent and child its effecting the next element

Tags: javascript

I have an array of elements that I am displaying as a button and those have a close button. so I am using for each to assigning them and giving them click events. so both the functionality is working. but when I close an element the next element is been automatically called.

```
function printAll() {
    data.innerHTML = '';
    allFile.forEach((a, i) => {
        data.innerHTML = ` ${data.innerHTML}  <div id="${allFile[i].id}" class = "btn" >${allFile[i].path} <span class="close">&times; </span> </div>`;
    });
    allFile.forEach((a, i) => {
        let temp = document.getElementById(allFile[i].id);
        temp.addEventListener('click', () => {
            open(allFile[i].path, allFile[i].type)

        });

    });
    allFile.forEach((a, i) => {

        let temp2 = document.getElementById(allFile[i].id).querySelector(".close");
        temp2.addEventListener('click', () => {
            close(i);
        });
    });
}

function close(is) {
    let aas = allFile.splice(is, 1);

    for (let i = 0; i < allFile.length; i++) {

        if (i > is - 1) {
            allFile[i].id--;

        }
    }
    allFile.forEach(a => console.log(a.id))
    allFile.forEach(a => console.log(a.path))
    window.setTimeout(() => {
        printAll();
    }, 600);
}
```

so the expected output is that when I close a box/button it removes and other elements just appear without calling the click event of the next element.

but what happens is that when I close it, it just calls the click event of the next element.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simplify your script and also make the genertion of HTML markup simpler. Below is my take on doing what you want to do:

```js
const allFile=[{id:1, path:"first path"},
               {id:2, path:"second path"},
               {id:3, path:"third path"},
               {id:4, path:"fourth path"},
               {id:5, path:"fifth path"},
               {id:6, path:"sixth path"},
               {id:7, path:"seventh path"} ];
printAll(allFile,".show"); 


function printAll(allFile, where) {
 const cont=document.querySelector(where);
 cont.innerHTML = allFile.map(a=>`<div id="${a.id}" class = "btn" >${a.path}<span class="close">&times; </span> </div>`).join('\n');
 cont.onclick=ev=>{
   if (ev.target.className=="close"){ // a ".close" button was clicked ...
     let el=ev.target.parentNode      // this element should be removed
     el.style.display="none";         // make it invisible
     allFile.splice(allFile.map(e=>e.id).indexOf(+el.id),1); // remove array element
     console.log(allFile)             // show array
   }
 }
}
```

```css
.btn {border: solid 1px grey; margin:6px}
.btn span {font-size:3ex; cursor:pointer}
```

```html
<div class="show"></div>
```

In my script I use "delegated event handling". I. e. I set up a click handler on the parent element with class "show". The event will only fire if a `.close`-button was clicked. And then I operate from the clicked element "upwards": I identify the parent element that needs to be removed and from there I find the array element which I remove by applying the `Array.splice()` method.